# How to differentiate updating or inserting in GridView OnUpdating Event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, edititemtemplate

I'm working on my Web Application using ASP.NET, I came into a situation where I need to differentiate **UPDATIng** and **INSERTING** on GridView Updating Event.

```
 protected void GridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 {
    //conditional check
    if(Update Flage){
        //Call Update Function
    }
    else{
        //Call Insert Function
    }
 }
```

I have a **ItemTemplate** and **EditItemTemplate** in the GridView, when click on Edit Button (on ItemTemplate), then change to Update Button (on EditItemTemplate).

[image]

And I have a Add Button outside of GridView, upon clicking, add a new Row into GridView and change Button text to **ADD** as following code fragment:

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(ds.Tables[0].NewRow(), 0);
GridViewID.EditIndex = 0;

LinkButton cmdButton = GridView.Rows[0].FindControl("btnUpdate") as LinkButton;
cmdButton.Text = "Add";
```

I know there is InsertItemTemplate for row inserting, but in my situation I was using Button outside of GridView to add new editing row instead.

So, how can I differentiate editing or inserting on RowUpdating Event? Any recommended trick to achieve this? perhaps something like adding a HiddenField as a flag.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify event on basis of that command name value

eg.

```
 protected void GridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
     {
       string arg = e.CommandName.ToString();
    if(arg="Edit")
     {
     }
    else if(arg=="Update")
      {
      }
```

mark up

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" Text="Customize"  CommandName="edit"  CommandArgument='edit'  runat="server"> 
       </asp:LinkButton>
```